# Metropolis Hastings Kernel - Relation Indicator function and Dirac Mass

Tags: self-study, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Why does the indicator function is equivalent to the integral over the Dirac mass?

In my lecture notes the proof for the Kernel of the Metropolis Hastings is given as follows:

$$P(X^t \in \mathcal{X}|X^{t-1}=x^{t-1})=P(X^t \in \mathcal{X},A|X^{t-1}=x^{t-1})+P(X^t \in \mathcal{X},A^c|X^{t-1}=x^{t-1})$$
where  A is defined as the event "proposal accepted". This is equivalent to
$$\int_\mathcal{X}\alpha(x^t|x^{t-1})q(x^t|x^{t-1})dx^t+\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{X}(x^{t-1})P(A^c|X^{t-1}=x^{t-1})$$

The first half of that is obvious ($\alpha$ is the acceptance probability and $q$ the proposal). The way I understand the second half is: As the proposal is rejected $P(X^t \in \mathcal{X})=P(X^{t-1} \in \mathcal{X})$ which is deterministic at time $t$ such that $P(X^{t-1} \in \mathcal{X})=\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{X}(x^{t-1})$

The next step is not clear to me. **My question: Why**

$$\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{X}(x^{t-1})=\int_\mathcal{X}\delta_{x^{t-1}}(dx^t)$$

where $\delta_{x^{t-1}}(dx^t)$ is the Dirac Delta mass.
From which it obviously follows that

$$\mathbb{1}_\mathcal{X}(x^{t-1})P(A^c|X^{t-1}=x^{t-1})=\int_\mathcal{X}(1-a(x^{t-1}))\delta_{x^{t-1}}(dx^t)$$

where

$$a(x^{t-1})=\int_\mathcal{X}\alpha(x^t|x^{t-1})q(x^t|x^{t-1})dx^t$$